# Popup.js toggle button typeError

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to replicate this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gwtf3s4c/1/) and add a toggle on/off button to my popup in my chrome extension.

**popup.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <script src="popup.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <button id="toggle">OFF</button>
</body>
</html>
```

**popup.js**

```
console.log("popup.js running..")
var button = document.getElementById('toggle');
var isToggled = false;
button.onclick = function(e){
    isToggled = !isToggled;
    // Your code here
    button.innerText = isToggled ? 'ON' : 'OFF';
};
```

My error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'onclick' of null

why do I get this error on the bottun.onclick? How can I fix this?

Comment: Move `<script src="popup.js"></script>` right before the closing `</body>`

Comment: This totally worked. please, can you help me understand why?

Comment: Local scripts are loaded synchronously by default so only the HTML above the script tag has been processed into DOM.